# Stop an event in OpenLayers 2?

Tags: javascript, events, openlayers

I have a map with features. I want to klick on features and react to 'featureselected'.
I also want to be able to click somewhere else in the map.

```
  OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
    defaultHandlerOptions: {
        'single': true,
        'double': false,
        'pixelTolerance': 0,
        'stopSingle': false,
        'stopDouble': false
    },
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
            {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
        );
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
            this, arguments
        ); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
            this, {
                'click': this.trigger
            }, this.handlerOptions
        );
    }, 
    trigger: function(evt) {
        // do things
    }
  });



    var click = new OpenLayers.Control.Click();
    selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector);
    _map.addControl(selectControl);
    selectControl.activate();
    _map.addControl(click);
    click.activate();
    vector.events.on({
        'featureselected': onSelect,
```

When the feature is clicked, I DO NOT want to call the click function for the map.
What do I have to call in onSelect to prevent the event from propagating, bubbling? 
Right now both functions are called when I click on a feature.
I tried OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt), found evt.cancelBubble, cannot find evt.Bubbles

Thanks a lot,
Ropo

Answer (score 0):

I have an OpenLayers Map with an MouseOver-Control (Vector), with a SelectFeature (Vector) and also a Click-Event that searches GetFeatureInfo-Requests a the click position if nothing was found.

It might help you to add your Click-Control before the selectControl.

My init-function approximately looks like this in the following order:

```
oMouseOverCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature( oMouseOverVectorArray, { ... });
oMapObj.addControl( oMouseOverCtrl );
oMouseOverCtrl.activate(); 

oMouseClickControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature( oMouseOverVectorArray, { ... });
oMapObj.addControl( oMouseClickControl );
oMouseClickControl.activate();

oMouseClickControlInfotool = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({...});
oMapObj.addControl( oMouseClickControlInfotool );
oMouseClickControlInfotool.activate();
```

Comment: by the way: sometimes I get the click Event handed over to my last Wms-Layer - but it looks like that this only happens when I some other things don't work in my page